How to update swissup/breeze-evolution theme in magento?
I currently have the Breeze theme version swissup/breeze-evolution - 2.1.5. I need to update to the latest version. What steps should I take to do this?

Try this command:
composer require -w swissup/breeze-evolution:2.1.5

